# Create and manipulate from a variable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've a - probably - easy question. I need to create and manipulate a
variable from its html content.

Here is the JS code :

```
var table = '<table class="my-class1 my-class2"><thead><tr><td>123</td></tr></tbody></table>';
$('myVar').html(table);
$('myVar').removeClass().addClass('my-class3');
console.log($('myVar').html());
```

But unfortunately, I'm just unable to succeed....

Thank you,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is `myVar`? What output are you expecting to have?

Comment: which class are you trying to remove? "$('myVar').removeClass().addClass('my-class3');" Please provide a jsfiddle for your problem.

Comment: `$('myVar')` i think you should tell us what exactly is this??? Now it seems your question is getting closed.....:(

Comment: Ok, it was too clear in my brain. My purpose was to create from scratch a variable with html content. So, this variable isn't in the DOM. And my problem was to manipulate the variable (in my exemple, add a class, remove another one...) like any DOM object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
   var table = '<table class="my-class1 my-class2" border="1" cellpadding="5"><thead><tr><td>123</td></tr></tbody></table>';
   $('#myVar').html(table);
   $('#myVar').removeClass().addClass('my-class3');
   console.log($('#myVar').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myVar"></div>
```

It depends on `myVar`,

If it a `jQuery element` then use it like,

```
myVar.html(table);
```

If it is an `Id` then use it like,

```
$('#myVar').html(table);
```

And If it is a `Class` then use it like,

```
$('.myVar').html(table);
```

To get more abount **[jquery-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Let it is an `Id` then your code should look like,

```
$('#myVar').html(table);
$('#myVar').removeClass().addClass('my-class3');
console.log($('#myVar').html());
```

Comment: if you have some doubts regarding question then first clarify them in comments section and then post a answer.

Comment: @Kartikeya the man explored pretty much every possibility and gave a solution the poster can work with... Actually, as for what SO is, it is even better to give a general works-for-all answer then such a specific one that only the poster himself has benefit of it. IMO quite unfair you are downvoting him...

Comment: @giorgio...plz stop guessing because i am the downvoter...

Comment: @Kartikeya I have some doubt thats why I gave some common examples of jquery selector with the referral link, may be OP doesn't know. And if you are here to give your answers then most welcome to do that.

Comment: I am upvoting this answer because it solves problem in every respect

Comment: @Kartikeya: If Rohan had posted an answer that **only** asked "what is `myVar`" then that would not be acceptable. This answer is acceptable, for the reasons enumerated by giorgio, and doesn't violate the guidelines in that help article in any way.

Comment: I was trying to manipulate any variable from the DOM if the variable contained some html code (not into the .html / .php). But I discovered something that I didn't know before and - I think so - that obscured my brain. The .html() method doesn't return the outterHtml ! And this point was the key of my problem.